# For loop in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop

I have a data which has 3 different numbers of "Equipement" and each "Equipement" has different contract date ( start_date and end_date).

Screen Data:
[image]

I want to write a script which I can say that for every "Equipement" If the first line of "end_date" match the second line of "start_date" in days, so I should do ("start_date" - 1 day) in the second line AS a new_end_date for the first line.

I've made an attempt, but for just the two first lines ( not generalized):

```
    SELECT[Ref]
          ,[Equipement]
          ,[start_date]
          ,[end_date]
          ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, (SELECT [end_date] FROM [DWDiagnostics].[dbo].[Test1] WHERE [Ref] = 1290), (SELECT [start_date] FROM [DWDiagnostics].[dbo].[Test1] WHERE [Ref] = 1380)) < 0 THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, [start_date]) ELSE [end_date]
          END AS [new_end_date]  
          FROM [DWDiagnostics].[dbo].[Test1]
```

Here's a screen of the result I want

[image]

SQL code for the Data ==>

```
    DECLARE   @Test TABLE
              (
                   Ref VARCHAR(10),
                   Equipment   VARCHAR(10),
                   start_date  DATE,
                   end_date  DATE
                )
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('1290','9999','2014-03-01','2016-04-16')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('1380','9999','2016-04-01','2018-05-17')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2000','9999','2018-05-01','2020-06-27')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2900','9999','2020-06-01','2021-06-29')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('1556','8888','2016-01-01','2017-02-27')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('1876','8888','2017-02-01','2018-04-26')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2897','8888','2018-04-01','2020-03-30')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2653','7777','2017-09-01','2018-10-14')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('4536','7777','2018-10-01','2019-11-13')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2987','7777','2019-11-01','2020-12-27')
    INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2776','7777','2020-12-01','2021-11-30')
    SELECT * FROM   @Test;
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The language/dialect you are writing here is T-SQL, and the RDBMS is SQL Server *not* SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). SSMS is just an IDE like application specifically for SQL Server; SSMS actually has nothing to do with the problem other than it's the application you are writing the code in (like Visual Studio) In truth, however, looping is one of the *last* things you want to do in T-SQL; SQL is a set based language and so you want to use set based methods. Iterative methods, like a loop, perform terribly in SQL.

Comment: use the lead / lag functions to get the previous date https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Help us understand the desired output. I can't find any logical explanation from the data or your description about what values are returned for new_end_date.

Comment: @SeanLange If I understand the OP's question correctly, they are looking to truncate overlapping contract periods so that the prior contracts for an equipment ID always ends at least one day before the new contract begins.

Comment: @RBarryYoung that is what I was thinking also but looking at the new end date it doesn't seem to line up with that to me. Sometimes it is the day prior, other times it is the last of the month prior, other times it is the same day and other times it just some random date.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thank you for your reply, yes at least one day before the new contract begins, so I will be sure to not have days matches in the same equipment ID's new contract

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for your reply, to be more clear, when a new contract begins, the old one should end one day before the new begins.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your reply, it's my first time using SQL, I'm just a beginner, and I'm to Python before SQL, I didn't know that, thank you so much for your explanations

Comment: Ahh that makes sense now. Look at the comment about using LEAD/LAG. That is the way to handle this. If you can provide table definition and sample data in a consumable format I can show you how to write that.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't know how to provide you the data in a consumable format here in this forum? Thank you for your help !

Comment: Either type out and post create table and insert statements or use something like https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: Does Ref is unique?

Comment: @SeanLange I've inserted the data code in the end of the post, thank you in advance

Comment: @RF1991 no, Each contract has his own Ref. One ID Equipment can have multiple Refs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting sample data and tables structures. Makes this so much easier to work on the problem. This should work based on your explanation of the issue. However, some of the new_end_date values you posted as desired do not match up to your description. For example, with Equipment 9999 you have the second start_date as 4/1/2016 but in your desired output you show 3/30. The day before 4/1 is 3/31. There are some other examples with dates like that in your desired output that are slightly off the day before.

```
DECLARE   @Test TABLE
(
    Ref VARCHAR(10),
    Equipment   VARCHAR(10),
    start_date  DATE,
    end_date  DATE
)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('1290','9999','2014-03-01','2016-04-16')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('1380','9999','2016-04-01','2018-05-17')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2000','9999','2018-05-01','2020-06-27')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2900','9999','2020-06-01','2021-06-29')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('1556','8888','2016-01-01','2017-02-27')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('1876','8888','2017-02-01','2018-04-26')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2897','8888','2018-04-01','2020-03-30')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2653','7777','2017-09-01','2018-10-14')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('4536','7777','2018-10-01','2019-11-13')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2987','7777','2019-11-01','2020-12-27')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('2776','7777','2020-12-01','2021-11-30')
    
select *
    , new_end_date  = isnull(dateadd(day, -1, lead(start_date, 1)over(partition by Equipment order by start_date)), end_date)
from @Test
ORDER BY Equipment desc
    , start_date
```

Comment: I can't find words to thank you.. This is a clear explanation. That's true, the day before 4/1 is 3/31, it was just an error from me. Thank you so much again , one more function learned today :)